# Why Does Calling Expand and Select on a PUT result in LESS information being returned - Acumatica REST API

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

In the example for ***Acumatica: "Lesson 2.1: Updating a Customer Account"*** the sample code will update the customer's Contact info, based on retrieving it by the email address. It expands the MainContact and selects CustomerID and CustomerClass:

```
https://localhost/MyStoreInstance/entity/Default/18.200.001/Customer?$filter=MainContact/Email eq 'info@jevy-comp.con'&$expand=MainContact&$select=CustomerID,CustomerClass
```

[image: Postman Screenshot 1]
The values that are returned include CustomerID, CustomerClass PLUS a fully loaded BillingContact record, comprising 2150 Bytes of data like this:

```
{
    "id": "0b88d208-297a-4b81-a20c-39d27bace10a",
    "rowNumber": 1,
    "note": "",
    "BillingContact": {
        "id": "e1133b8a-fca9-4885-8e4c-09a85808f025",
        "rowNumber": 1,
        "note": null,
        "Activities": [],
        "Address": {
            "id": "4f1719aa-6eb0-4551-a143-ad2139e135aa",
            "rowNumber": 1,
            "note": null,
            "AddressLine1": {
                "value": "1000 Pennsylvania Ave"
            },
            "AddressLine2": {},
            "City": {
                "value": "San Francisco"
            },
            "Country": {
                "value": "US"
            },
            "PostalCode": {
                "value": "94107-3479"
            },
            "State": {
                "value": "CA"
            },
            "custom": {},
            "files": []
        },
        "Attention": {
            "value": "Mister. Jack Green"
        },
        "Attributes": [],
        "Campaigns": [],
        "Cases": [],
        "ContactID": {
            "value": 12417
        },
        "DisplayName": {
            "value": "Jevy Computers"
        },
        "Duplicates": [],
        "Email": {
            "value": "green@jevy-comp.con"
        },
        "Fax": {},
        "FirstName": {},
        "JobTitle": {
            "value": ""
        },
        "LastName": {},
        "MarketingLists": [],
        "MiddleName": {},
        "Notifications": [],
        "Opportunities": [],
        "Phone1": {
            "value": "+1 (777) 380-0089"
        },
        "Phone1Type": {
            "value": "Business 1"
        },
        "Phone2": {},
        "Phone2Type": {
            "value": "Business 2"
        },
        "Relations": [],
        "Title": {},
        "UserInfo": null,
        "WebSite": {},
        "custom": {},
        "files": []
    },
    "BillingContactSameAsMain": {
        "value": false
    },
    "CustomerClass": {
        "value": "INTL"
    },
    "CustomerID": {
        "value": "C000000003"
    },
    "custom": {},
    "files": []
}
```

However, when I explicitly ask for BillingContact to be **Expanded**, I get LESS information than I get when I omit it from the EXPAND command altogether. (I get 1235 bytes in return.)

[image: Postman Screenshot 2:]

```
{
    "id": "0b88d208-297a-4b81-a20c-39d27bace10a",
    "rowNumber": 1,
    "note": "",
    "BillingContact": {
        "id": "e1133b8a-fca9-4885-8e4c-09a85808f025",
        "rowNumber": 1,
        "note": null,
        "Attention": {
            "value": "Mr. Jack Green"
        },
        "ContactID": {
            "value": 12417
        },
        "DisplayName": {
            "value": "Jevy Computers"
        },
        "Email": {
            "value": "green@jevy-comp.con"
        },
        "Fax": {},
        "FirstName": {},
        "JobTitle": {
            "value": ""
        },
        "LastName": {},
        "MiddleName": {},
        "Phone1": {
            "value": "+1 (777) 380-0089"
        },
        "Phone1Type": {
            "value": "Business 1"
        },
        "Phone2": {},
        "Phone2Type": {
            "value": "Business 2"
        },
        "Title": {},
        "WebSite": {},
        "custom": {},
        "files": []
    },
    "BillingContactSameAsMain": {
        "value": false
    },
    "CustomerClass": {
        "value": "INTL"
    },
    "CustomerID": {
        "value": "C000000003"
    },
    "custom": {},
    "files": []
}
```

Clearly I do not understand how the expand command is operating in a PUT. Can anyone explain it to me?

Why does including BillingContact in the **expand** command give me ***less*** BillingContact information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute a Put request, Acumatica automatically add expands for the entities your are touching, including subentities, so you see Address under `BillingContact`.
When you add expand on the billing contact, it overrides the default expands and you do not see `Address` any more. 
To get `Address` in the result, you add another expand : `BillingContact/Address`

Same applies to all other entities